# overriding showMap

Tags: geotools

This code is not working as needed. I  need just to make a window with addlayer button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
//import org.geotools.renderer.GTRenderer;
//import org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapPane;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;



public class App2 {

public static void showMap(final MapContent map) throws IOException {

       final JMapPane mapPane = new JMapPane(map);
      // mapPane.setMapArea(map.getLayerBounds());

       JFrame frame = new JFrame("cis");
       frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       frame.add(mapPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

      /* JButton zoomInButton = new JButton("Zoom In");
       zoomInButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  mapPane.repaint(); } });
       buttons.add(zoomInButton);

       JButton zoomOutButton = new JButton("Zoom Out");
       zoomOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  mapPane.repaint();  } });
       buttons.add(zoomOutButton);

       JButton pamButton = new JButton("Move");
       pamButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   mapPane.repaint(); } });
       buttons.add(pamButton);
       */
       JButton addLayer = new JButton("Add Layer");
       addLayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           try{
               File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
            if (file == null) {
                return;
            }
            FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
            SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
            Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
            Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
            map.addLayer(layer);
             }catch(IOException f){}
        } });
       buttons.add(addLayer);

       frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(600, 400);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String s){

           MapContent map = new MapContent();
            map.setTitle("Climate information system");
            JMapFrame.showMap(map);



    }
}
```

Comment: how is it working?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
JMapFrame.showMap(map);
```

This will call `showMap` method of the `JMapFrame` class or geotools but not your `App2` class `showMap` method. Please correct it and try again.